# compiling openssh 5.5p1 with jpake exploit

Tags: openssh, c

I am having some trouble using the jpake exploit and compiling it with openssh 5.5p1 :https://github.com/seb-m/jpake/archive/master.zip

This is the error I am getting:
  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAL0v.png)

Comment: Please do not post code and error messages as an image!

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSH versions older than 8.0 only support OpenSSL 1.0.x or older. You are trying to compile with OpenSSL 1.1.x, which has an incompatible API.